# python find items in a list given indices

Tags: python, list

Is there any other FASTER way to find the items at index locations.

```
items = ['aaa','sss','ddd','fff','gggg','hhhh']
indices = [1,3,4]

My way: 
[items[i] for i in indices]
```

Comment: Is it a bottleneck in your application? How do the typical `items`, `indices` look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the same indices over and over, you might do better with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
getter = itemgetter(1,3,4)
desired = getter(items)
```

According to my simple benchmark, `itemgetter` is about 2.5x faster (but I didn't time how long it takes to actually construct the `getter` function to begin with).

```
>>> items = ['aaa','sss','ddd','fff','gggg','hhhh']
>>> indices = [1,3,4]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> import timeit
>>> getter = itemgetter(*indices)
>>> def list_comp(items=items,indices=indices):
...     return [items[i] for i in indices]
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('getter(items)','from __main__ import getter,items')
0.2926821708679199
>>> timeit.timeit('list_comp()','from __main__ import list_comp')
0.7736802101135254
>>> getter(items)
('sss', 'fff', 'gggg')
>>> list_comp()
['sss', 'fff', 'gggg']
```

Comment: If you include the time it takes to create the `getter` then [the difference is minimal for the data](http://ideone.com/9p89Ym)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- Good to know, thanks for doing the timing there -- although my hope was that it was the same items that were being retrieved repeatedly ...

Comment: Thanks. The time calculation was of great help